# Draw image on canvas by uploading file using file uploader

Tags: file-upload, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw image on canvas, the image file is uploaded using File Uploader. It's working fine on Chrome and IE10 however it breaks on IE9.The createObjectURL method which i am using is not supported on IE9(i guess..).Is there any alternative way to get this work on IE9?

My code for drawing image on canvas

```
    var URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL ;
    if ($("#rwAddImage_C_RadUploadImgfile0")[0].files[0] == undefined || $("#rwAddImage_C_RadUploadImgfile0")[0].files[0] == null) {
        alert('Please select image');
        return;
    }

    var url = URL.createObjectURL($("#rwAddImage_C_RadUploadImgfile0")[0].files[0]);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;

    img.onload = function () {

        img_width = ($('#rwAddImage_C_txtImgWidth').val() != "" ? $('#rwAddImage_C_txtImgWidth').val() : img.width);
        img_height = ($('#rwAddImage_C_txtImgHeight').val() != "" ? $('#rwAddImage_C_txtImgHeight').val() : img.width);

        context.drawImage(img, imgPosX, imgPosY, img_width, img_height);
        img_update();
        cPush();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IE9 doesn't support a way to "upload" images to javascript without taking the detour over a server. So the only way to solve this problem for IE9 would be to upload the image to a server and then download it again from that server when the upload has finished.

This will require some server-sided programming using PHP, NodeJS, ASP, JSP or any other server-sided web technology you are familiar with and have available.